# After uploading laravel website, I am not able to use other website files

Tags: php, apache, laravel, laravel-4

After I uploaded my website to godaddy server, I changed the root directory to point at the laravel folder.

The website is working fine but now I am unable to use other files in non-laravel folders :-

```
www.mywebsite.com/secondwebsite/index.html
```

I am unable to see the webpage at "secondwebsite"

After I change debug from false to true in config.app.php - I get the following error message :-

```
Symfony \ Component \ HttpKernel \ Exception \ NotFoundHttpException
```

I just checked -  I can view the second website once I copy the folder in the public directory of laravel.

But what do i do if I want the second website not in the laravel folder?

Answer (score 1):

By default, apache is looking inside public Laravel folder, in the root of your server directory.Settings related to that directory are stored inside **.htaccess** file. If you have more then one project on a server, then they represents two paths inside main server directory.
Like on localhost, you  will have to register two virtual hosts and that depends on your server settings.

Locally it is easy. Add new virtual host into apache conf and create new host name in you local machine.